# How to give a TextBox type object to a thread

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startRequest));
    t.Start(textBox1);
}

void startRequest(object textBox1)
{
    textBox1.Text = "hello";
}
```

here I get an error that textBox1 doesn't have a property Text, in the main thread its all okay, but in the new thread I get an error ,how to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to create background thread in Windows application to change properties of your controls on WinForm? Don't do that - this won't work.

Comment: is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must cast your `object` to Type `TextBox` before using its Text property.

```
void startRequest(object textBox1)
{
    MethodInvoker mi = delegate
    {
        TextBox tempTextBox = textBox1 as TextBox;
        if (tempTextBox != null)
            tempTextBox.Text = "hello";
    };

    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(mi);
}
```

Its also better to check for null, if the casting fails.

Comment: i guess you should specify the normal way of `casting` and the reason for not using it

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. - now this :(

Comment: it looks like there is now way to access to a textbox from another thread, only from the main?

Comment: @Zecrow, You can, there was a mistake in my code, check now plz

Comment: Wow, yeah it worked, but just for curiosity, why so complicated code?, just for adding some text...anyway thanks

Comment: @Zecrow, You may read [Thread Safety - Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Object does not have property, You need to `type cast` object to `TextBox`, you wont be able to access text box though as your current thread is not `GUI thread`. You can use `MethodInvoker` To invoke the code in GUI thread as follow.

```
void startRequest(object textBox1)
{
    MethodInvoker mi = delegate {         
        ((TextBox) textBox1).Text = "hello";
    }
    if(InvokeRequired)
       this.Invoke(mi);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access UI component from thread other than UI thread. You will get exception here

```
tempTextBox.Text = "hello";
```

if you try to do it from another thread.